# Removing specific entry from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I store a new entry in core data like this:

```
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
    newManagedObject.setValue("Test1", forKey: "name")

    // Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        abort()
    }
```

My question is how can I delete an entry (for example `Test1`) without an indexPath of an UITableViewCell?

UPDATE:

The fetchRequest:

```
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name)
    var error : NSError?
    let results = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you would delete the object by doing:

```
context.deleteObject(newManagedObject)
```

If you need to delete the object from some place in your code where you do not have a reference to the managed object itself, you could fetch it, based e.g. on its name attribute, then delete it.

This is how you can get all MOs whose name matches `name`:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entity: entityName)
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
let results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I need to delete the object from some place in my code (don't have a reference). Can you give me an example how to fetch it based on its name attribute?

Comment: I updated my question how it's working. I have the MOs `Test1`, `Test2` and `Test3`. How can I delete `Test2`? Is this the correct way: `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == Test2", name)`? I'm using Swift for about 1 month. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == Test2")` or `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)`

Comment: and the to delete it: `context.deleteObject(results)` right?

Comment: that's an array, so you should iterate over it and delete objects one by one. If you are sure that only one object with the given name is there, you can do: `context.deleteObject(results.firstObject)`

Comment: If I use `context.deleteObject(results.firstObject)`, I get the following error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. Do you know why?

Comment: You should add a cast: `context.deleteObject(results.firstObject as NSManagedObject)`

Comment: If I add a cast, I get the following error: `Cannot invoke 'deleteObject' with an argument list of type '(NSManagedObject)'`.

Comment: In Xcode 6.3, you need to force the cast (`as!` instead of `as`): `context.deleteObject(results.firstObject as! NSManagedObject)`